# Datapoints in Xrange highchart are not uniformly getting aligned to the center

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to align the data points to center(vertically) in each data row of the graph using my data , but the alignment is pretty much inconsistent. Some points start at the top of the row and some at the middle and few of them near the bottom . I tried using the point placement property and I was able to alter the position . The problem I faced was , the data points/data lines(green) at the top could be brought to middle but the points/lines(green) that were present in the middle and bottom moves further down and looks very inconsistent . I have tried most of the properties available but all in vain . Could someone guide me how the point position is calculated in the graph and is being positioned . How to bring the data points to center in each row. I have attached the screenshot/image for your reference. I have encircled the data points in blue .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCe3P.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtjlr.png)

Comment: Can you put some example on JSFiddle and paste it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced your problem in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/70ts5myc/

The empty space is reserved for columns with similar data values to prevent overlapping. To prevent that disable grouping:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            grouping: false
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ahe4Lugf/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.xrange.grouping

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks a ton ppotaczek .

Comment: After doing this  the problem I am facing is that if I have two data points in the same month say one if from 10th March 2021- 30th April 2021 and the other from 22nd March 2021 - 24th April 2021 both of them gets merged into one . I need two separate lines/data points one below the other . Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Hi @Vinay Kumar, That is why grouping is enabled by default. How would you like to show such points?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek - I need two separate lines/data points one below the other . Is that possible?

Comment: Ok, but do you want to use these two lines always or only if two data points overlap each other?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek Can I dynamically assign the gridline witdth based on the data, say if i have  data points more than 25 in a row i want the gridline with to be 100 px and if its less than 25 i need it to be 20 px. How can i achieve that? Pls suggest

Comment: Hi @Vinay Kumar, Could you create a new question with a more detailed description of the problem?